# Cannot implicitly convert type X to 'T' when the 'where' condition is in the class declaration

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

Consider this code:

```
class Model  {}

interface IApi1<T> where T: Model 
{ 
   T Create(T entity); 
}

interface IApi2 
{ 
   T Create<T>(T entity) where T: Model; 
}

class Foo {
    IApi1<Model> api1;
    IApi2 api2;
    
    public T Do1<T>(T d) where T: Model => api1.Create(d); // ERROR
    public T Do2<T>(T d) where T: Model => api2.Create(d); // WORKS
}
```

Why is the line marked as "ERROR" gives me the `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model' to 'T'"` but the seemingly same code works in the next line? The only difference in the `IApi2`from `IApi1` is that the where condition moved from the class declaration into the method declaration. Why does it make a difference?

I am not looking for a solution; I am merely curious why the behavior.

Comment: Well, what if `api1` is declared as `IApi1<SomeDerivedModel>` but `Do1` is called with `OtherDerivedModel`? That would break, right? `IApi2` doesn't because you're implicitly passing `T` down from the `Do2` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me rename some of the type parameters, so that it is easy to see what we are talking about:

```
interface IApi1<TApi1> where TApi1: Model 
{ 
   TApi1 Create(TApi1 entity); 
}

interface IApi2 
{ 
   TApi2 Create<Api2T>(TApi2 entity) where TApi2: Model; 
}

class Foo {
    IApi1<Model> api1;
    IApi2 api2;
    
    public TDo1 Do1<TDo1>(TDo1 d) where TDo1: Model => api1.Create(d); // ERROR
    public TDo2 Do2<TDo2>(T d) where TDo2: Model => api2.Create(d); // WORKS
}
```

When a type parameter is declared on the type, like in the case of `IApi1`, it is "fixed" (or "determined") at the moment you write the type. That is, the moment you wrote:

```
 IApi1<Model> api1;
```

it is decided that `api1.Create` would take in a `Model`, and return a `Model`. The type parameter (`TApi1`) is substituted with the type argument (`Model`).

On the other hand, if a type parameter is declared on a method, it is not "fixed" until you call that method. `IApi2.Create` can take any `TApi2` and return that same type `TApi2`, where `TApi2` is a `Model`. It is only when you *call* `Create`, that C# decides what `TApi2` is.

Both `Do1` and `Do2` declares type parameters too, and I've called them `TDo1` and `TDo2`. Note that these are distinct from the type parameters `TApi1` and `TApi2`.

In `Do1`, you try to return what `IApi1.Create` returns. This doesn't work, because `IApi1.Create` returns a `Model`, but `Do1` is declared to return `TDo1`, which if you recall, will only be determined when the caller calls `Do1`. The caller of `Do1` might as well pass another `Model` subclass as the type argument for `TDo1`!

In `Do2`, returning `IApi2.Create` is okay, because the actual type that `IApi2.Create` returns (i.e. `TApi2`) is not determined until you call it. In this case, it is inferred that `IApi2.Create` will return `TDo2`, which, in turn will be determined when someone calls `Do2`.

Comment: makes total sense, thanks